# Golang Mgo - How to view result?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

It looks like I'm able to successfully connect to my Mongo Database. I'm able to view that there are 30 records in my collection. How do I actually view the records though?

```
enter code here
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type User struct {
    id        bson.ObjectId `json:"-" bson:"_id"`
    firstName string        `json:"first_name"`
    lastName  string        `json:"last_name"`
    email     string        `json:"email"`
    regId     string        `json:"registration_id"`
    regKey    string        `json:"registration_key"`
    password  string        `json:"password`
}

func main() {

    session, err := mgo.Dial("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX")
    if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
//res := []User{}
c := session.DB("cd").C("auth_user")

res := []User{}
fmt.Println(c.Find(bson.M{}).All(&res))
fmt.Println(len(res))
fmt.Println(res)
fmt.Println(res[0])
fmt.Println(res[0].email)
}
```

The output of the above is:

30
[{      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      } {      }]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the field names.

```
type User struct {
  ID        bson.ObjectId `json:"-" bson:"_id"`
  FirstName string        `json:"first_name"`
  LastName  string        `json:"last_name"`
  Email     string        `json:"email"`
  RegId     string        `json:"registration_id"`
  RegKey    string        `json:"registration_key"`
  Password  string        `json:"password`
}
```

The BSON codec ignores unexported fields.

Comment: It is right. Don't forget to click to link at word export. It explains why fields that name starts with lower letter are not exported.